# Troubles with Bidirectional One-To-One JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I'm coding a CRUD JPA web application. My goal is that a given parent Vehicle can only have a single child Driver, but during runtime this same Driver can instead be assigned to another Vehicle and vice versa. To my understanding, this could be accomplished via an OneToOne relationship.

I've tried some different approaches, but to no success. I can assign a Vehicle to a Driver just fine, but when I try to update/create a new Vehicle and give him a Driver, via controllers, nothing happens. I can only do it the other way around. I'm assuming this is because Vehicle is the parent and I can only create a new relation by updating a parent.

My question is, is it possible to make these updates bidirectional and how can I achieve that?
I've tried using a shared primary key, using a foreign key, using a join table. The result is always the same and I can't quite grasp why. I have an OneToMany relationship working on this application and it works as I expect it to work. I can update on one side or the other, delete on one side or the other. Both entities have been updated. OneToOne? Parent seems to have all the power.

This is what I'm working with right now:

Driver

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "drivers")
public class Driver {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int age;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "driver")
    private Vehicle vehicle;
```

Vehicle

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "vehicles")
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String make;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String model;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int mileage;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int year;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int fuel;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
    private Driver driver;
```

And just for reference, this is the OneToMany relationship I have and that I'm happy with. I'd like my OneToOne to have the same behavior, except I don't need to save a list of entities, only one.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="stops")
public class Stop {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="route_id")
    private Route route;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="routes")
public class Route {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "route_id")
    private List<Stop> stops = new ArrayList<>();
```

Any tips would be appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: You are creating a new vehicle, so it must be inserted or cause an exception to be thrown. So how are you setting the driver on this new vehicle and saving it? Your Route-Stop relationship is wrong with problems of its own - it is not a correct bidirectional relationship and should have caused validation warnings in your persistence unit, as both 'sides' of the mapping will attempt to set/control the stops.route_id column. The Route.stops property should remove the joinColumn and be marked as mappedBy "route". In both models, both 'sides' of the relationship need to be managed to be saved

Comment: @Chris I hope I understood your question, I have a form when creating a new Vehicle that lets me pick one of the Drivers in the DB and then I save the Vehicle in a CRUD repo. Same goes when updating a Vehicle.

I also tried your changes in the Route-Stop relationship and as soon I try to delete a Route I get a Whitelabel Error Page indicating a ConstraintViolationException. Also, when I try to update the list of Stops in a given Route, it doesn't work, everything stays the same. Do you think this might be related to my Controllers?

Comment: @Chris ConstraintViolationException happens only when I try to deleted a Route with Stops, I can delete Routes with no stops just fine aswell as Stops that are part of a Route

Comment: Your back end needs to use the 'driver' id and fetch it, and use that instance in your new (or existing) vehicle. This read should be done in the same transactional/Entitymanager context as the writes, and you must set both sides of this bidirectional relationship. That means you must decide what do to and should happen if that vehicle already has a driver. As for route/stop issues, those are expected because now you have a 'single' relationship between them. What you had before was two separate unidirectional relationships, both trying to control the stops.route_id.

Comment: Your controller logic must not be correct to handle a bidirectional relationship, and only setting one side. If you delete a Route, you must null out the Stop's reference to it and save that stop. As you said, it is the parent (or owner) that controls the foreign key in the database. What you have (two unidirectional relations) may appear to work, but will have other consequences, both to caching and to inadvertent data overwrites (route will still reference a stop in memory, even if the database doesn't, and that difference can be picked up and inadvertently undo changes in your app

Comment: @Chris sorry to keep bothering you but I really am having trouble understanding. Isn't the goal of a bidirectional relationship that I can make changes to either owner or child and the changes are propagated to the other? Why do I have to be concerned on setting both sides?

Comment: No, a bidirectional relationship is to give you a reference to follow in your object model in both directions. Treat your entities as POJOs and it should be more clear. If you set one side only, then you have two conflicting relationships; one is null, the other has a reference. A parent should not unilaterally disown a child; the child will still have its parent reference. Even if the database reflects the change, the model won't unless/until it is refreshed, and with caching, who knows when that will be. So it is up to the application to maintain both sides and keep them in synch.

Comment: Even if you aren't using or concerned with caching, best practice is still to update both sides of the relationship - JPA will only issue updates it needs to the database, so it doesn't generate more update statements, and chances are good it'll have read in the parent and child to calculate the changes, if not to send you the data in the first place.